# GRANTing permissions across different databases (schemas)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, permissions

I'm securing the DB by only allowing interaction with the DB through a series of Sprocs; pretty common fare.

I've dug up and modified a script which loops through and assigns the user EXECUTE permission for all non-system SProcs. It works a treat except that I'd ideally like to add it to the Master DB so that I can easily use it for any subsequent projects. Yes, I could save simple as a .sql file but I'd prefer it this way.

The problem is that I don't know how to dynamically refer to objects in another DB. For example, I can easily query on MyDB.dbo.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES, but if the DB name is dynamic (e.g. @MyDBName), how can I query the objects in this DB?

Edit: Thanks to the posters below, I now have a working solution:

```
USE [master]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGrantExec] 
@User sysname,
@DB varchar(50),
@Target varchar(50)
AS 
/*---------------------------- SQL 2005 + -------------------------------*/

SET NOCOUNT ON

-- 1 - Variable declarations
DECLARE @SQL varchar(8000)

-- 2 - Create temporary table
Set @SQL =
'USE @DB

DECLARE @MAXOID int
DECLARE @OwnerName varchar(128)
DECLARE @ObjectName varchar(128)
DECLARE @CMD1 varchar(8000)

CREATE TABLE #StoredProcedures
(OID int IDENTITY (1,1),
StoredProcOwner varchar(128) NOT NULL,
StoredProcName varchar(128) NOT NULL)

-- 3 - Populate temporary table

INSERT INTO #StoredProcedures (StoredProcOwner, StoredProcName)
SELECT ROUTINE_SCHEMA, ROUTINE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_NAME LIKE ''' + @Target + '%''
 AND ROUTINE_TYPE = ''PROCEDURE''

-- 4 - Capture the @MAXOID value
SELECT @MAXOID = MAX(OID) FROM #StoredProcedures

-- 5 - WHILE loop
WHILE @MAXOID > 0
 BEGIN 

    -- 6 - Initialize the variables
    SELECT @OwnerName = StoredProcOwner,
    @ObjectName = StoredProcName
    FROM #StoredProcedures
    WHERE OID = @MAXOID

    -- 7 - Build the string

    SELECT @CMD1 = ''GRANT EXEC ON '' + ''['' + @OwnerName + '']'' + ''.'' + ''['' + @ObjectName + '']'' + '' TO @user''

    -- 8 - Execute the string
    Print @CMD1
    EXEC(@CMD1)

    -- 9 - Decrement @MAXOID
    SET @MAXOID = @MAXOID - 1
 END

-- 10 - Drop the temporary table
DROP TABLE #StoredProcedures'

Set @SQL = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@SQL, '@DB', @DB), '@User', @User), '@Target', @Target)
--Select @SQL
--Print @SQL
Exec (@SQL)
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Comment: You might want to look at the cleaner one I found: SELECT @sp_executesql = quotename(@dbname) + '..sp_executesql'
EXEC @sp_executesql @CMD1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similiar to @Cade's answer, the way to do this is to use dynamic sql.  Before each call to a database table, add '@DbName.'  Then replace the @DbName with the actual database name (the database name can't be passed as a variable in SQL, so you have to do the replace).

Also Cursors are normally considered evil for performance reasons, however using one in this case makes sense.  For one, it would greatly simplify the procedure, plus since you're only going to run this once during application updates, you probably won't notice a performance hit, even if it added an extra second or two (which I doubt it would add anywhere near that much).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGrantExec]
@User SysName,
@DbName VarChar(512)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Sql VarChar(1024)
```

SET @Sql = 'DECLARE @OwnerName varchar(128)
DECLARE @ObjectName varchar(128)
DECLARE @Cmd1 VarChar(128)
DECLARE ProcCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT ROUTINE SCHEMA, ROUTINE NAME
FROM @DbName.INFORMATION SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINENAME NOT LIKE ''dt %'' AND ROUTINE TYPE = ''PROCEDURE''
OPEN ProcCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM ProcCursor INTO @OwnerName, @ObjectName
WHILE @@FETCH STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @CMD1 = ''GRANT EXEC ON '' + ''['' + @OwnerName + '']'' + ''.'' + ''['' + @ObjectName + '']'' + '' TO '' + ''@user''
EXEC (@CMD1)

FETCH NEXT FROM ProcCursor INTO @OwnerName, @ObjectName
END
CLOSE ProcCursor
DEALLOCATE ProcCursor
'

SET @Sql = Replace(Replace(@Sql, '@DbName', @DbName), '@user', @User)
EXEC (@Sql)

END

You can call this using:  EXEC [spGrantExec] 'bob', 'Northwind'

Sorry the spacing is a little off in the sp.  Developed using Sql 2005.

Answer (score 2):

I found [another technique, which I think is cleaner](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_table):

```
SELECT @sql = 'CREATE VIEW ...'
SELECT @sp_executesql = quotename(@dbname) + '..sp_executesql'
EXEC @sp_executesql @sql
```

This relies on setting the database context by calling sp_executesql in the other database (just like one could call an SP in any database).

In your case it would be equivalent to:

```
SELECT @sp_executesql = quotename(@dbname) + '..sp_executesql'
EXEC @sp_executesql @CMD1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the double exec technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483798/creating-stored-procedure-in-another-database/483868#483868).

In your case, instead of just:

```
EXEC(@CMD1)
```

You would have:

```
SET @CMD1 =
    'USE OtherDatabase;
    EXEC (''' + REPLACE(@CMD1, '''', '''''') + ''')'
EXEC(@CMD1)
```

Comment: Interesting. I can see the principle, but haven't yet digested the finer details. but looks promising...

Comment: I wish I could have split the award for the accepted answer - thanks anyway.