# SQL dynamically create stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create a script to create/setup a group of stored procedures that will all be fairly similar.

So I am trying to loop through this code, changing the `@DATABASE_NAME` and `@TableName` when needed.

```
/* Start loop */
    DECLARE @create_stored_procedure nvarchar(max) 
    SET @create_stored_procedure = N'
       USE [' + @DATABASE_NAME + ']
       CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_imp_' + @TableName + ']
       AS
       BEGIN
           PRINT(''doing something'')
       END'
    EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @create_stored_procedure
/* End loop */
```

But I am getting errors saying

> 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.

or

> 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.

All the solutions online suggest using GO, but that won't work in dynamic SQL.

Does anyone know a possible solution for SQL Server 2005?

Comment: did you tried by Splitting `use db` and `create procedure` as two dynamic sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't call the solution intuitive, but apparently [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/483868/2400222) works. I prefer the look of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/793362/2400222) though.

Answer (score 1):

Try with spiting USe DB and create procedure. Like this

```
DECLARE @create_store_procedure nvarchar(max) 

SET @create_store_procedure = N'
   USE [' + @DATABASE_NAME + '] '
EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @create_store_procedure

SET @create_store_procedure = N' 
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_imp_' + @TableName + ']
   AS
   BEGIN
       PRINT(''doing something'')
   END '

 EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @create_store_procedure
```

This is working perfectly for me

Comment: This fails for me. Created a stored procedure on my "master" database. Appears to be dependent on the database you are connected to.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Nithesh's answer and that didn't work for me it ended up creating the store procedure in the master table. Zec's answer worked. Creating a dynamic query inside my dynamic query.

```
DECLARE @create_store_procedure nvarchar(max) 
DECLARE @use_db nvarchar(max)

SET @create_store_procedure = N' 
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_imp_' + @TableName + ']
   AS
   BEGIN
       PRINT(''doing something'')
   END '

SET @use_db = N'
USE [' + @DATABASE_NAME + '] 
DECLARE  @sub_create_store_procedure nvarchar(max)
SET @sub_create_store_procedure = ''' + REPLACE(@create_store_procedure, CHAR(39), CHAR(39) + CHAR(39)) + '''
EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @sub_create_store_procedure 
'

 EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @use_db
```